# Code never executed, not getting any errors

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to use AJAX and HTML5 to handle file uploads from clients computer to a folder on the server.

Right now the `alert` message below in addition to the `success` function never get executed and I am not sure why. I am not getting any JS errors. Both the php script and the folder to save the file to are granted full read/write permissions.

It is extremely difficult for me to get this to work without seeing any errors.

I appreciate any assistance in identifying the cause of this problem, and getting some errors or at least the alert message to execute.

Many thanks in advance!

JQuery

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'upload.php',  //server script to process data
        type: 'POST',
        xhr: function() {  // custom xhr
            myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if(myXhr.upload){ // check if upload property exists
                myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',progressHandlingFunction, false); // for handling the progress of the upload
            }
            return myXhr;
        },
        //Ajax events
        success: function(data){
            alert("OK");
            $('body').html(data);
        },
        // Form data
        data: formData,
        //Options to tell JQuery not to process data or worry about content-type
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false

    });
```

HTML

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="file" type="file" />
    <input type="button" value="Upload" />
    </form>
    <progress></progress>
```

upload.php

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["name"] != NULL) {
  if (file_exists("uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
    echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
  else
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
}


?>
```

Comment: Somewhat unrelated, try using the keyword "debugger;" in your JS files alongside Chrome's inspector.  It will halt execution when it hits that keyword and let you see what's going on.  Otherwise the complete: function() { } hook might be another useful point to hook into when diagnosing XHR because complete is always called.

Comment: You don't have an error handler. Create an `error: function() {}` error callback as described in the docs http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ And always develop JavaScript with your browser's console open. Watch the XRH take place and inspect its response there in the network section of the browser's dev tools.

Comment: Have you tried debugging with the developer tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an error handler as well.

```
$.ajax({
  success: function(data){
    console.log("OK");
    $('body').html(data);
  },
  error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
    console.log('An error has occurred!');
    console.log(textStatus);
    console.log(errorThrown);
  }
});
```

Javascript won't throw any errors for a failed ajax request, so you need to catch them yourself.

Comment: +1, Thanks for the reply! I am getting the following error: `Object {readyState: 0, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}`, any idea what might be causing this?